# Compressor or cooling fans not running 2002 Odyssey

Tags: honda, odyssey

Replaced the compressor charged 32 oz 134a went to check it out and the compressor  or condenser  fans will run. All the fuses look good. Any
ideas..

Comment: Please rephrase your question.  Your title says one thing, the text the opposite.

Comment: Sounds like its working? Over charged the system? Adding 32oz when irt only needs 28oz will have too much coolant. This will send a signal to the computer not to turn on the AC because the pressure is too high. Recover your coolant, by half maybe, run it temporarily and test. Add more coolant as needed to get it in the proper gauge section.

Comment: Plate say 32 oz of 134 when i jump the pressure  switch to grlund compressor  and fan works but Will not work it own.